# Create Vaadin form using Binding form to data

Tags: forms, data-binding, user-interface, vaadin

I'm trying to create form with Vaadin using "Binding form to data" with this class:

```
public class Job {

    private String nom_projet;
    private String svn;
    private String planning1;
    private String planning2;
    private String goals;
}
```

with getters and setters.

When I try this everything works fine:

```
final Form form = new Form();
Job bean = new Job();
BeanItem<Job> item = new BeanItem<Job>(bean);
form.setItemDataSource(item);
```

I tried to add a custom field like its described in "Book of Vaadin" so I created this class:

```
public class MyFieldFactory implements FormFieldFactory  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Field createField(Item item, Object propertyId, Component uiContext) {
        Select select = new Select("goals");
        select.addItem("compiler:compile");
        select.addItem("clean install");
        select.addItem("clean");
        select.addItem("package");
        select.addItem("test");
        select.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
        return select;
    }
}
```

But when I wanted to add this statement to `MyApplication.java`:

```
form.setFieldFactory(new MyFieldFactory());
```

I got "`setFieldFactory`" underlined and 3 choices:

> - () Cast argument 1 to FieldFactory
> - Change to setFirldFormFactory(...)
> - Let 'MyFieldFactory' implements 'FieldFactory'

When I click on:

> - Let 'MyFieldFactory' implements 'FieldFactory'

custom field does not appear in form.

Answer (score 2):

the `setFieldFactory` method take a `FieldFactory` as parameter and your `MyFieldFactory` class implements `FormFieldFactory` wich is not the same.

In Vaadin javadoc, the `setFieldFactory` is mark as deprecated and they hint you to use `setFormFieldFactory(FormFieldFactory formFieldFactory)` instead.

Using this method will solve your problem.

Regards.